# What's best Python open source library to draw chart?

Tags: python, charts

What's best open source library in Python to draw chart/diagram? 2D is necessary, and 3D is good if provided together. and it has to accept simple input data format like csv.

I googled one called: `matplotlib`, how is it and any others?

It should be best in terms of the reliability, performance, simple use and easy integration, etc., or a combination of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the official python wiki:

> Over the years many different plotting modules and packages have been
>   developed for Python. For most of that time there was no clear
>   favorite package, but recently matplotlib has become the most widely
>   used.

matplotlib highlights for me:

- easy to learn (based on matlab traditions but also features object-oriented paradigm)
- reliable (well-supported, updated, and documented)
- robust (check out some of the [stuff you can do with it!](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/trunk-docs/gallery.html))
- large community of users (well-liked and highly regarded in many circles)
- easy to integrate (works natively alongside numpy/scipy)
- accepts TeX commands for special formatting
- quite the accepted standard for both simple and complicated chart drawing

I personally use it for many purposes including making diagrams for work presentations, graphics for school papers, and even charts and images for formal scientific documentation in mathematics and computer science. Especially the TeX stuff is particularly useful to me.

So I think you had the right idea. Matplotlib came up first in your google search because it's by far the most reputable, and in general the most useful.

In case you want to investigate some others, here's a link to an overview of some available plotting tools on the official python wiki: http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Plotting#Plotting_Tools

Comment: Thanks, from the above link, matplotlib appears at the top - does it indicate it's most popular one at least from this site's perspective?

Comment: yes, I knew it, I certainly know this basic site, at least I know the word 'python', ah! the key question here is, on the offical python wiki site, does the order of the library list reflect the popularity?

Comment: Thanks. sorry, my stupidity! I read the official list again carefully, it says: "Over the years many different plotting modules and packages have been developed for Python. For most of that time there was no clear favorite package, but recently matplotlib has become the most widely used", so you're right.

Comment: Thanks. Generally speaking, can I ask, how about the **quality** of the generated chart pictures by matplotlib, comparing to the most popular chart softwares in any other language, no matter free or commercial, do you have any idea, according to your experience?

Comment: Never really used many other languages for plotting because it's too complicated... But in general the quality of my matplotlib charts is dependent on the amount of time I spend fine-tuning them. You can get simple stuff REALLY easy, but it takes a little bit of tweaking to get exactly what you want, you know? But the great thing is that you can tweak it in pretty much any way you want, and it's designed specifically to be tweakable.

Comment: I think I have got enough idea to choose **matplotlib**. thanks!

Comment: If you wanna be really impressed check out some of the charts on the "gallery": http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/trunk-docs/gallery.html -- it's also good for surveying when you know there's a specific type of image you want to get, but you have no idea where to start: try to find something like it in the gallery or the examples, and work from there. That's the #1 feature of matplotlib: extensive documentation and examples.